# Should the built-in ability to embed YouTube and Soundcloud in your question/answer be part of the faq?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

So, the ability to embed audio occurred to me almost instantly.  I'm sure it did for most of you too.

Looking back at an [early meta post](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/58/2569), it did then as well :)

Only upon reading those old posts, however, did I run into [this meta post](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/2569).  Yay!

If it occurred to me quite soon after finding the site, and it occurred early on to those here at the inception of the beta, it seems likely that it occurs to many many contributors.

Hopefully, I just missed it?  But whether I missed it or not, I think it should be a more prominent piece of information.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick glance at the FAQ has my head spinning with all the information there.

I think it's a great idea to advertise the feature, but I think maybe a better place would be in the formatting help on the right when you are asking a question.  Then it will be in front of the user as soon as they begin typing a question and will keep them from having to open the FAQ and sort through it.

Comment: I think that's a good idea.  Perhaps it should actually be in the faq, with a direct link to the new section in that info bar on the right.  There are only a couple links there... I think it could still stand out.  A link that said, "How to embed audio/video in your question >>" would fit right in there.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. Other opinions?